# Rails config error 500

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm currently deploying a rails app on a debian server.
It previously worked well and I can't figure out why I've been missing since I change the app directory.

I'm now getting a 500 internal server error and the logs are :

```
[Mon Aug 21 16:06:35.755626 2017] [core:error] [pid 60088] [client NN.NN.NN.NN:NNN] End of script output before headers: 

==> /var/log/apache2/XXXX.XXXX.com.access.log <==
NN.NN.NN.NN - - [21/Aug/2017:16:06:35 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 845 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
NN.NN.NN.NN - - [21/Aug/2017:16:06:35 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1752 "http://XXXX.XXXX.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
```

I already checked the secret.yml file and also the mysql credentials.

Config :
- ruby 2.3.0
- rails 5.0.0.1

Other websites (not rails) on the same server work well.

The user has write access on tmp/* in the app directory.

Do you have any idea what I could be missing ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the log more?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only log I have !

Comment: @taitrantuan : I updated the question with the whole block but I'm not sure it would change anything.

Comment: Set the PassengerLogLevel to 7 in your apache virtualhost, and then restart and make a request then post the logs that generates.

Comment: I still got the same error log :|